# Match exact string using string.Contains() method in c#

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have an html content. I'm parsing the content using HtmlAgilityPack.
I Need to replace attribute
 '**align = "middle"**' with '**align = "center"**', I'm using function

```
if(htmlDoc.DocumentNode.OuterHttml.Contains("align = "middle""))
htmlDoc.DocumentNode.OuterHttml.Replace("align = "middle","align = "center"")
```

But if condition is returning true even for `**valign = "middle"**` !

What is that i need to put in if condition other than `Contains()`?

Comment: Contains means at least one instance is met...if you want exact use equal()

Comment: what is your sample input? is valigh = middle part of a bigger string or is it the complete string?

Comment: I don't think you've defined the problem well enough for anyone to give an answer - for example, is `xyz align="middle" abc` a match or not?

Comment: Are you trying to parse an html?

Comment: @I4V:  yes I'm trying to find match inside an html content.

Comment: @Raghavendra Then stop using string operations and use a real html parser. http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: I Have rephrased the question. undo down votes!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> yes I'm trying to find match inside an html content.

Then use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).  Your code would be something like.

```
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(HtmlString);

var tds = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@align='middle']");
```

or something like this using LINQ

```
var tds = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("td")
                .Where(td => td.Attributes["align"].Value == "middle")
                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

It not that clear what you are trying to achieve. `String.Contains` checks if a given string is *contained* in another (probably larger) string, so if it is a substring.

Maybe you want  to know if they are same, then use `Equals` or `==`:

```
bool same = string1 == string2;
```

or you want to know if it starts  with a given string, then use `StartsWith`:

```
bool startsWith = string1.StartsWith(string2);
```

or you want to ignore the case (.NET is case sensitive):

```
bool equalsIgnoreCase = string1.Equals(string2, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

the same with `StartsWith`:

```
bool startsWithIgnoreCase = string1.StartsWith(string2, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

finally the case-insensitive contains equivalent using `IndexOf`:

```
bool containsIgnoreCase = string1.IndexOf(string2, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0;
```

Comment: I'm checking if a given string is contained in another (probably larger) string and with an exact match!

Comment: You're correct that's what you're doing, and you're getting exactly the expected results from doing that - but what are you trying to do? If you're trying to parse HTML, the correct solution to your problem is to use an HTML parser, not string functions.

Answer (score 2):

if your string is like "blablabla align = 'align = \"middle\" blablabla" then you can do:

```
Contains(" align = \"middle\" ") // spaces before and after
```

But how others says it's hard to understand what you want exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
string str = "valign = \"middle\"";
string search = "align = \"middle\"";

int ix;

while ((ix = str.IndexOf(search, ix)) != -1)
{
    if (ix == 0 || !char.IsLetterOrDigit(str[ix - 1]))
    {
        break;
    }

    ix++;
}

bool success = ix != -1;
```

This will work even for `valign = "middle";align = "middle"`

It checks if the letter that precede the beginning of the match is a non-`IsLetterOrDigit` (if present). If yes, it `break`s, otherwise it return searching for a match from the next character.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the exact string match from a list of strings

```
if ( keywords.Find(str => str == keyword) != null )
```